# Get Each user recent post in wordpress

Tags: recent-posts, multi-author

I have a Multi Author Blog, I want to show Recent post of each user / author. Image has been attached for more convenient, see the Red selected area where author's recent post is showing.

[image: Author Recent post]

Comment: What have you tries so far, what research have you done. Please [edit] you question and add all relevant code and explain where your code is failing

Answer (score 0):

To do this we will need to do 2 queries:

1) Get a list of all the users on the site via [wp_user_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

2) Get posts from all the users using [wp_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

The code:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( 'Author' );

if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
 foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
  echo '<h2>' . $user->display_name . '</h2>';
  $query1 = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=4&author_name='.$user->display_name );
  while ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
   $query1->the_post();
   echo '<p><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></p>';
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
 }
}
```

It's not tested but it should display like:

Author 1:
 - Post 1  Post 2  Post 3  Post 4

Author 2:
 - Post 1  Post 2  Post 3  Post 4

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I've already user list, i just need each user 5-8 last with thumbnail.

Comment: you would use get_the_thumbnail() to get the thumbnail for each post, put it after the $query1 ->the_post()

Comment: It's difficult for me to add this code in it as I have an author card that have Avator & showing user name as well. Check the screenshot please [link](http://i61.tinypic.com/11hz3nc.jpg)
Give me only that code which show recent post with image.

Comment: Anyone else know.